# Simulating a VHDL design using custom libraries

Tags: vhdl, simulation, xilinx

I am trying to make a simple VHDL project to brush up my memory. I am using a file *half_adder.vhd* to create another file *full_adder.vhd*, which I wish to simulate. These files are not in the same project. I am using the Xilinx ISE version 14.7.

My code synthesizes perfectly fine, and passes the syntax check. I can also create RTL schematics. However, whenever I try to create a test bench for the full adder, I get the following error messages:

> ERROR:HDLParsers:3317 - "E:/workspaceXilinx/FullAdder/full_adder.vhd" Line 23. 
>       Library half_adder cannot be found.
>
> ERROR:HDLParsers:3513 - "E:/workspaceXilinx/FullAdder/full_adder.vhd" Line 24.
>       Declaration all can not be made visible in this scope since design unit
>      half_adder is not a package.

I have added *half_adder.vhd* to the *work* library, so I'm not sure why the library cannot be found. Here are the two files I am using:

**half_adder.vhd**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity half_adder is
    port(a, b: in STD_LOGIC;
            s, c: out STD_LOGIC);
end half_adder;

architecture Behavioral of half_adder is
begin
    s <= a xor b;
    c <= a and b;
end Behavioral;
```

**full_adder.vhd**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

library half_adder;
use half_adder.all;

entity full_adder is
    port (a, b, cin: in STD_LOGIC;
            s, cout: out STD_LOGIC);
end full_adder;


architecture Behavioral of full_adder is
signal s1, c1, c2: STD_LOGIC:='0';
begin

    HA1: entity work.half_adder port map(a, b, s1, c1);
    HA2: entity work.half_adder port map(s1, cin, s, c2);
    cout <= c1 or c2;

end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `work` library refers to the library currently being compiled. If you have not explicitly created a `half_adder` library in the design tool, it will not exist. All you need to do is remove this `library` and `use` clause relating to `half_adder`; it is not required.

Comment: Thank you for the swift answer.